# Sum of the lengths of all diagonals in a regular polygon

Tags: lagrange-multiplier, polygons

I believe that the sum of the lengths of diagonals of a regular polygon ($n$-gon) is always greater than or equal to any other irregular polygon ($n$-gon) **inscribed in a circle**.

**For example for a 4-gon**, if we consider a regular $4$-gon, then the two diagonals pass through the centre of a circle, resulting in the sum of the diagonals' lengths twice the diameter. Considering any other $4$-gon (irregular), the sum of the lengths of the diagonals is not greater than $2\times$ the diameter.

**Case : 5-gon**
I proved that the sum of the lengths of diagonals in a regular $5$-gon is maximum compared to any $5$-gon (irregular polygon). I used Lagrange's multiplier to prove it.

**Case : $n$-gon**
I tried proving the same for an $n$-gon using Lagrange's multiplier, where we need to maximize the sum of the lengths of all diagonals with respect to $$\theta_1+ \theta_2 + \dots + \theta_n =2\pi,$$ but unable to do the calculation as the number of variables increases. Here $\theta_i$ is the angle subtended to the centre of a circle by the side $a_i$ of the polygon.

I  believe that the  sum of the lengths of diagonals is  maximum if   $$\theta_1 = \theta_2 = \dots = \theta_n,$$ which is possible only in a regular polygon.

Edit: same question posted in mathoverflow, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/398248/sum-of-the-lengths-of-all-diagonals-in-a-regular-polygon

Comment: It is not true that the sum for a nonsquare quadrilateral is always less than twice the diameter. If it's a rectangle, the sum is equal to twice the diameter. Also, you have introduced a symbol $\theta$ without telling anyone what it means (but if it means what I think it means, then your last assertion is incorrect).

Comment: OK, then saying the $\theta_i$ are all equal is the same as saying all the sides are of the same length, which is the same as saying it's a regular polygon.

Comment: Yes, using Lagrange's multiplier I have proved that for 5-gon, the sum of the length of diagonals is maximum if 5-gon is a regular polygon. But I am unable to prove it for n-gon. And refering to your first comment, sum of the length of diagonals is maximum for regular 4-gon. Please check. Thank you

Comment: The sum of diagonals for a rectangle is the same as the sum of diagonals for a square. Please check.

Comment: Yes. Can we say same about 5-gon? I mean is there exists any other  5-gon (irregular) whose sun of of diagonals is better than regular 5-gon.

Comment: I think you are missing my point. You write, "Considering any other 4-gon(irregular), the sum of the length of diagonals is always less than 2×Diameter," and that is simply false.

Comment: Yes, I got your point. I changed my query accordingly. Does it make any sense now ?

Comment: Yes, much better.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out.  What about other n-gon, n > 4?

Comment: I have proved that area and perimeter of the regular n-gon is always greter than the irregular n-gon. Can this lead to the proof of the sum of diagonals? This is another approach for the problem.

Comment: I think you're right for $n=5$. I don't think that case needs Lagrange multipliers; I think all you need is that for angles between $0$ and $\pi$, $\sin a+\sin b\le2\sin((a+b)/2)$. I don't know about $n>5$, you might be right that the regular polygon maximizes. I doubt that the area and perimeter results will be enough to settle the $n\ge6$ cases.

Comment: Yes, I too doubt that  the area and perimeter results will help. So, I was using Lagrange's multiplier. But it is difficult to work with increase in  the number of variables.  I tried using induction using 4 and 5 as base case. But I failed. Anyway thank you .

Comment: I don't know whether that will help. The question is, how to get a grip on the sum for the polygons that aren't regular?

Comment: Yeah, it is difficult to get a grip on it. I am struggling with the same. I will explore further and let you know if I get anything.

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/398248/sum-of-the-lengths-of-all-diagonals-in-a-regular-polygon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is true (presumably but this is not complete), in fact a proof can  be done along these lines, sketch. First you prove that for three points $A,B,C$ on a circle, the maximum of the distance $AB+BC$ for $A$ and $C$ fixed is for $B$ middle  of the arc $\overset{\frown}{AC}$. (Here is a proof in French [A proof](http://www.les-mathematiques.net/phorum/read.php?8,2228908,2229994#msg-2229994)), you should prove also that getting away from the middle of the arc will decrease the distance sum. From that a circular (and averaging) reasoning  for any $n$-gone inscribed in a certain circle gives a convergence towards the regular polygone as  maximal  for the sum of diagonals.

For example here is   the figure for  a pentagone, for general $n\ge 6$  say $n=6$ you pick the middle of the two arcs: points $P$ and $Q$, take the  point that maximises the sum of the three diagonals  submerged, it should be inside the arc $\overset{\frown}{PQ}$ etc
An animation is possible maybe someone could make this... [image]

EDIT i realised this is more complicated than this anyway i'll keep the answer.

Comment: This answer is not very rigorous yet.

Comment: Actually, I made a rigorous version of proof  filling in some of the details; hope it matches up

Comment: @ToniMhax- I got your idea. But I feel it is difficult to generalize for all the diagonals.  I proved it for 5-gon using Lagrange's multiplier as in 5-gon, for each diagonal only two angles are to be looked for. I mean  for diagonal line $P_1P_3$,  we need to look $\theta 1, \theta 2$. So, it is easy to solve.

Comment: Yes no proof...(sry)

Comment: I can see the proof (based on your idea), but it is difficult to jot down.  Some minor thread is missing in my understanding.

Comment: The proof of C.Park is very good. It is what i thought  to formalize...the cycles defined cover the diagonal set and each cycle sum is maximal when all are equal.

Comment: Can we argue for each cycle separately? And how can we say that adding all cycles will give the sum of diagonals.

Answer (score 2):

For simplicity, let us consider the index $i$ of $P_i$ as the member of $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

We aim to show a stronger criterion : given points $P_1,P_2,...,P_m$ on the unit circle $\Omega$ lying in the counter-clockwise order, for each $k<m$ such that $gcd(k,m)=1$, we have
$$\sum_{j=1}^m \overline{P_j P_{j+k}}\le \sum_{j=1}^m\overline{Q_j Q_{j+k}}$$
, where $Q_1,...,Q_m$ are vertices of a regular $(m)$-gon inscribed in $\Omega$.

Assuming this, we can easily show the original conjecture observing that the collection of all diagonal lines of the convex $n$-gon $P_1 P_2...P_n$ is partitioned into the cycles of the form above.

(Explicitly speaking, we can write

$$\sum_{|i-j|\ge 2}\overline{P_iP_j}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\sum_{j=1}^{gcd(k,n)}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n/gcd(k,n)}\overline{P_{ki+j}P_{k(i+1)+j}}\right)$$
You can check this holds since each segment of LHS is counted at least twice in RHS, and the total count of segments of RHS is $(n-1)n$, which is exactly twice of the total number of terms in LHS.
)

For better intuition, I post an example of $n=8$.

[image]

The collection of the diagonal segments of the octagon above is the disjoint union of the red, green, blue-colored chains plus the four main diagonals. Assuming our criterion is correct, we can argue that the total length of the segments of each color (including the main diagonals) is maximized when the polygon is regular, which concludes our proof.

Now, to show the criterion, we first exclude the trivial case $m=2$, and allow some of $P_j$'s to be the same. (but not in a switched order)

Writing $P_j=e^{i\theta_j}$, one can easily observe that the set of such $(\theta_1,...,\theta_m)\in \mathbb{T}^m$ is compact.

(Here, $\mathbb{T}^m$ is the $m$-dimensional torus $\mathbb{R}^m/\mathbb{Z}^m$ with the natural metric)

Thus, there exists a pair $(\theta_1,...,\theta_m)$ that maximizes the sum.

Now, observe that for each $j$, $P_j$ contributes only to two distinct segments : $\overline{P_jP_{j+k}}$ and $\overline{P_jP_{j-k}}$.

By the sine addition formula $\sin \alpha+\sin \beta=2\sin(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2})\cos(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2})$, this can be maximized only if $\overline{P_jP_{j+k}}=\overline{P_jP_{j-k}}$.

It follows that the lengths $\overline{P_jP_{j+k}}$ are all equal, which requires $P_1...P_m$ to be vertices of a regular $(m)$-gon, ending the proof of the desired criterion.

P.S. This is a formalization of the great idea suggested by Toni Mhax.

Comment: By this "collection of all diagonal lines of the convex n-gon P1, P2, ..., Pn is partitioned into the cycles of the form above", you mean to say all diagonals will be partitioned, but I doubt that some diagonals will not be taken into the account. Please make it is easy for me. I did not get the first part.

Comment: You should pay attention when you say each $j$ contributes to two distinct segments this works only in $n=5$...

Comment: @PawanMishra - I added some more explanation. Hope this one helps.

Comment: @ToniMhax - It seems that this works for general $n$, could you see this again and tell me if there is anything suspicious?

Comment: @C.Park changing any two diagonals or the position of a point will change the others also wich makes it tricky. You may take $P_jP_{(j+2)}=P_jP_{j-2}$ but maybe this decreases the other distances....

Comment: @ToniMhax - Here we are dealing with the sum over each color 'separately'. For the example of the octagon, the regular octagon is a maximizer of the length of each of (red/green/blue)- colored part as well as each main diagonal.

Comment: Ok. I see thanks!

Comment: I am still struggling to see the proof, though the diagram helped a lot to understand things going behind the proof. Thanks, @C.Park

Comment: Can you please explain the first inequality? for m =6, k=1, 5, then $\overline {p_1p_2}$ will be there which is not part of any cycle.  Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: In your approach, you can say that all blue edges length are same, similarly for green. Since the green edge and blue edge are of same type of diagonals, their length should be equal to each other.  Correct me if I am wrong in my arguments

Comment: @PawanMishra - For the first inequality, yes, it holds when $k=1,m-1$ as well. It is not used at all to cover the case $m=n$, but it is used when $m|n,m\neq n$. For example, for the case of an octagon, you have the cycles $p_1p_3p_5p_7$ and $p_2p_4p_6p_8$, the green and blue edges, and we need to show they are also maximized when the given polygon is a regular one.

Comment: Summarizing my argument, I planned to show that for every octagon, each of the sums of red/green/blue-colored segments and each main diagonals are less than or equal to that of the regular octagon, and to show that, I used compactness argument to show there exists a maximizer of the red-colored sum (for example) and forced that such a maximizer should have the property that all segments have equal length, as you mentioned above.

Comment: As a side note, the regular polygon is the only optimizer when $n\ge 5$, while all non-degenerate rectangles are answers when $n=4$.  This can be shown since we can choose some number $m$ between $2$ and $n-2$ with $gcd(m,n)=1$ and that requires all the arcs $p_1p_{m+1},...$ to have the same length, which holds only if the polygon is regular.

Comment: @C.Park I got the idea now. Can u explain "by the sine additional part".. bit confused there. You are saying $p_j, p_{j+k}, p_{j-k}$ this forms a triangle and sum of two sides is maximum only if they are equal. Can I get something to read about it. Any link or material will do . Thanks...